# Jquery/Javascript conflicts moving nav and slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently purchased a jquery news slider to use on my website, and when I add it to my homepage, the calls in the header move the navigation and slideshow so that the entire page is messed up.

The page looks like this before I add the news feed: http://www.bovinsnbcattle.ca/
And like this after I add the news feed (jquery/javascript/css): http://www.bovinsnbcattle.ca/index2.html

Is there an easy way to fix this conflict, or do I have to buy a different news slider?

Comment: Why would you *buy* jQuery code?! That's new... never heard of that before. Isn't that a huge waste of money?

Comment: lol it was 6 dollars, and worked better than any free ones I could find... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with bootstrap.css line 661,

```
ul,
ol {
  padding: 0;
    /* the left margin 25px cause the problem, remove or comment this line */
 /* margin: 0 0 10px 25px; */
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thanks so much, can I ask how you figured that out?

Comment: I just use chrome dev tools. As your original page is fine, so I just delete the new css file one by one, and when bootstrap.css is gone, the page is fine. So I know the problem is with bootstrap.css. And then, just inspect the nav ul, and find the style came from bootstrap.css, that's how find the exact line.

Comment: Again, thanks so much. I do use chrome dev, but don't know how to delete complete css file one-by-one. But thank you!

Comment: It's easy, on Elements panel, find the css link element in the head tag, then right click and "Delete node"